# Keycloack database vs spring boot database

Tags: database, spring-boot, keycloak

for example i have a spring boot blog where i have two tables `users` and `blog_posts`.  `blog_post` has of course column name `user_id`. Now when i migrate to Keycloack how can i handle this when all users are stored in keycloack database. The users primary id in keycloack is not an integer and i cannot store in `blog_posts` `user_id` as string because it is not optimal for the performance. How can i make relations to this users? Can anyone explain me how the architecture should looks like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can map your id keycloak id to your user_id in your table user(Add a user_id_keycloack) or create a table user_keycloack(user_id, user_keycloack). When your user connect for the first time, get the keycloack id and map it to your new user_id. When the user connect later, use the keycloack id to find user_id. Use user_id to get blog_posts. Don't use keycloack id like primary key.

Josselin